# Accepting different types of JSON array input?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS/Jersey project where I'd like to make things easier for my clients.

Currently a POST body to a service is like this:

```
POST http://localhost:7101/account/2274321/pieces/
{
    "piePieceIds": [
        1
    ],
    "cakePieceIds": [
        2
    ],
    "splitName": "Split"
}
```

I can map the arrays to an input object using

```
private List<Long> piePieceIds;
private List<Long> cakePieceIds;
```

This works fine. However, a client has asked for a change to make her life easier:

```
POST http://localhost:7101/account/2274321/pieces/
{
    "piePieceIds": [
        {
            "piePieceId": 1
        }
    ],
    "cakePieceIds": [
        {
            "cakePieceId": 2
        }
    ],
    "splitName": "Split"
}
```

How would I model each array to get the correct input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a POJO

```
public class PiecePie {
    private Long piePieceId;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and use a

```
private List<PiecePie> piePieceIds;
```

Do the same thing for the other field.